# Can I remove this Load bearing wall?

Tags: walls, structural, load-bearing

I wanted to find out if I can remove this wall?

[image: upstairs floor plans]

[image: Wall to remove]

Comment: How do you know it is load bearing? Which direction are the trusses or roof members running?

Comment: Load bearing walls are usually supported from the bottom of the house with beams or walls.  They also go across joists/trusses, not parallel with them.  Any wall can be removed.  Load bearing walls need a structural engineer to design the removal and new supports

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a Structural Engineer is required to safely and accurately make this determination. Lives depend on this being accurate and it shouldn't be entrusted to well meaning random strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove *any* wall.

*Sometimes* your **house falls down** if you don't first deal with supporting the loads the wall was supporting.

Since this appears to be part of a larger building(?), making parts of it fall down would probably result in people other than you being inconvenienced, and they would probably take legal action against you, so you apparently have twice the usual reason to consult a professional engineer licensed to practice in your locale before commencing destruction.